# Make checkbox checked, if the value is equals to 0

Tags: php, laravel

I have been in little weird situation. I am passing value as `0` when checkbox is checked in a particular scenario. But, during update or during any error scenario, the value returned be `0` and by default with value `0` checkbox is not being checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" {{ old('day_0', $data->day_0 == 0) ? 'checked' : '' }} class="onoffswitch-checkbox form-control @error('day_0') is-invalid @enderror" id="day_0" name="day_0" value="0">
```

I know this might be little weird to pass value as `0` but is there any way to tackle with this by passing value `0`

Comment: What is the function `old` doing?

Comment: @DarkBee It's a Laravel function to get the old request data if the validation failed.

Comment: @Qirel good to know :p

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis for the `old()` function doesn't match up to be valuables, with your current code, the second argument becomes an expression `$data->day_0 == 0` - meaning you end up getting `old('day_0', true) == 0` if you use the fallback value and that value was `0`.

The function `old()` will use the old value if it existed, otherwise `$data->day_0` as a default value if not.

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       {{ old('day_0', $data->day_0) == 0 ? 'checked' : ''  }} 
       class="onoffswitch-checkbox form-control @error('day_0') is-invalid @enderror" 
       id="day_0" 
       name="day_0" 
       value="0">
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But, its working fine for other number. I am making check for 7 days with 0 being sunday. There is no problem the field being checked when I go to edit form page. On edit page if its checked, it seems as checked and vice versa. But, when I got the valdiation failed, it remains always unchecked with my approach. And when I put that `== 0` outside that bracket as you mentioned its keep staying always checked. Let me know if you need more explation

Answer (score 0):

just use like shown below

```
<input type="checkbox" {{ old('day_0', $data->day_0) === 0 ? 'checked' : '' }} 
       class="onoffswitch-checkbox form-control @error('day_0') is-invalid @enderror" 
       id="day_0" name="day_0" value="0">
```

Comment: its making always checked when validation failed.